# Is there a way to enable durable links for JPG files?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-id, durable-links

I have enabled Document ID feature in one of the sites

Document ID feature seem to support only WOPI enabled files (all MS Office File formats + PDF)

Is there a way to enable durable links for JPG file types?

Answer (score 1):

Durable links are only a feature for Office files. There is specific logic that applies to them to enable this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The "Durable Links" feature in SharePoint only supports Office Documents. It does not support PDF and Image files (`.png`, `.jpg`).

Below are some related threads I found online:

1. [SharePoint 2016 Durable links](https://hangconsult.com/2016/06/15/sharepoint-2016-durable-links/)
2. [DOCUMENT ID / Durable links in SPO not working](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/document-id-durable-links-in-spo-not-working-at-all/m-p/200348)